# exception while trying to create the SessionFactory using hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, guice, hibernate-search

I have upgraded to hibernate 4 from hibernate 3.
but while trying to build the SessionFactory

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
sessionFactory = configuration.configure("app.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

I am getting the following exception

failed guiceFilter
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator to org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1767)
    at com.app.server.data.hibernate.SessionProvider.createSessionFactory(SessionProvider.java:55)
    at com.app.server.data.hibernate.HibernateDataSourceConnector.init(HibernateDataSourceConnector.java:39)
    at com.eng.server.services.ConfigurationServlet.init(ConfigurationServlet.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:593)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator to org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more

following are the jars in my project

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
antlr.jar
aopalliance.jar
avro-1.5.1.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.7.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-io-1.3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
gin-2.0.jar
guice-3.0.jar
guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar
guice-multibindings-3.0.jar
guice-servlet-3.0.jar
guice-throwingproviders-3.0.jar
gwt-servlet.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final.jar
hibernate-search-engine-4.1.1.Final.jar
hibernate-search-orm-4.1.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
javax.inject.jar
javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
lucene-core-3.5.0.jar
mvp4g-1.4.0.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
paranamer-2.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-jcl-1.6.0.jar
snappy-java-1.0.1-rc3.jar
```

Are the dependencies correct or I am missing on something?

Answer (score 1):

*org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator* of Hibernate Search version 4.1.1.Final implements *org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator* of Hibernate ORM v. 4.1.3.Final

so since your dependencies look like perfect, the only explanation is that you have some duplicate class definitions.

I'd suggest scanning your application with [JBoss Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale), a nifty command line tool which will explore your jars to find duplicates.

For example it looks like you have a duplicate *antlr*.